# Error while fetching account details from key pair [Java-stellar-sdk]

Tags: java-sdk

While fetching details of account using private SEED on stellar test net I am getting the below error:

```
 Error response from the server.
at org.stellar.sdk.requests.ResponseHandler.handleResponse(ResponseHandler.java:38)
```

Code Snippet .

```
SOURCE_KEY_PAIR = KeyPair.fromSecretSeed(StellarRedis.STELLAR_BASE_ACCOUNT_SEED.getKeys().getBytes());
SOURCE_ACCOUNT = STELLAR_SERVER.accounts().account(SOURCE_KEY_PAIR);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure about StellarRedis. This could be an alternative.

Say, your secret seed is "**__SEED__**".

//

```
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');
var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org');

var PUB_checkAc = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(__SEED__).publicKey()

server.loadAccount(PUB_checkAc)
  .then(function(account) {
        console.log('Balances for account: ' + PUB_checkAc);
        account.balances.forEach(function(assetBalance) {
          console.log('Name:', assetBalance.asset_code, ', Balance:', assetBalance.balance, 'Type:', assetBalance.asset_type);
        });
      })
```

https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Keypair.html#.fromSecret

The documents are often not up to date, so some methods fail without surprise. And please make sure your account has been created (funded already).